# Find insertion location in a sorted ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList` with sorted `Integer` numbers. I need to insert an element into the list, but i need to know at what location insertion should happen to maintain the ordering.

If I just add it and use `Collections.sort()` then I won't not be able to find the location of the inserted element.

Comment: Please check if your requirement still holds with my edits. Also please take some time to format your question appropriately, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ArrayList [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public int indexOf(Object o)
```

> returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified
>   element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

Comment: While a great choice, just keep in mind that Lists can contain duplicates, or objects which differ by address and yet return true on `equals(...)` so `indexOf(...)` might actually return the index of an equivalent object.

Comment: @EdwinBuck this is a reason why I did it with add+sort in my answer

Comment: Firstly there is a sorted array. When a new element comes in to  get added into the list i want to insert at the right place so that i dont need to sort it again. Also i need to change the corresponding element in another array. Thus i need to know the index where i am inserting this new element and pushing all the below by one step.

Answer (score 1):

From javadocs

```
add(E e)  Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
```

So to find index you can do `size-1` at the time of addition

Comment: I need to insert at the right position so that the order of the list remains sorted. So cant add at the end of the list

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(list.indexOf(10));` --- ull see answer as 5 . means at 5+1(6th position) the value is inserted .it is already said by Juned Ahsan